# yarn: MODULE_NOT_FOUND when file is right there

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I have a node.js repo that are returning a strange `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error when I try to run certain commands.

The repo, which I'll call `Foo`, is a [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org) environment. Running the `package.json` script for starting a local dev blockchain (`yarn chain`, which runs `npx hardhat node`) runs fine, but when I try running the test suite using the `package.json` script `yarn test` for the tests I want to run (which runs `npx hardhat test test/Foo/foo.test.ts`) I get:

```
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: Cannot find module '/home/x/code/Foo/test/Foo/foo.test.ts'
Require stack:
 - /home/x/code/Foo/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js
 - /home/x/Foo/node_modules/mocha/index.js
 - /home/x/Foo/node_modules/hardhat/builtin-tasks/test.js
 - /home/x/Foo/node_modules/hardhat/internal/core/tasks/builtin-tasks.js
 - /home/x/Foo/node_modules/hardhat/internal/core/config/config-loading.js
 - /home/x/Foo/node_modules/hardhat/internal/cli/cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at /home/x/Foo/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:349:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/home/x/Foo/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:346:14)
    at Mocha.run (/home/x/Foo/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:1006:10)
    at testFailures (/home/x/Foo/node_modules/hardhat/src/builtin-tasks/test.ts:57:13)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/x/Foo/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js',
    '/home/x/Foo/node_modules/mocha/index.js',
    '/home/x/Foo/node_modules/hardhat/builtin-tasks/test.js',
    '/home/x/Foo/node_modules/hardhat/internal/core/tasks/builtin-tasks.js',
    '/home/x/Foo/node_modules/hardhat/internal/core/config/config-loading.js',
    '/home/x/Foo/node_modules/hardhat/internal/cli/cli.js'
  ]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I have likely lost count of all the things I have tried, but they include:

- `rm -rf`ing `node_modules` and reinstalling
- clearing yarn's cache
- trying on a different version of node
- doing a fresh clone of the repo

The issues started around the time I was playing around with Yarn v2, so my current assumption is that I somehow messed up things with Yarn. Since I think this is a Yarn issue, I'll mention that I don't see a `.yarnrc.yml` or `/.yarn/` in the project. `yarn --version` currently gives me a v1 answer (`1.22.5`). I'm having second thoughts since running the npx command directly yields the same error, but I'll call it an operating hypothesis that I have somehow completely borked my environment so badly that even npm shudders at the result.

I think I can rule out this being a direct Hardhat issue. They said they've never seen this issue before, and it is difficult for me to find anything that could have caused the issue directly with Hardhat. Teammates using the same repo also have no problems, meaning it's something about my configuration, but all the Hardhat files are in a shared repo.

One strange tidbit is that for a bit the tests would run if I would use `yarn hardhat test test/Foo/foo.test.ts` instead of `yarn test test/Foo/foo.test.ts`, the tests would run normally. Someone told me something about global installs, so I wiped Hardhat from being a global install (without checking if it even was first, whoops), and now that doesn't work either.

In summary:

- I have a repo which is shared with others, and works for them. When I do some things in the repo (`yarn chain`) it works, but when I try to run the test suite, it tells me `MODULE_NOT_FOUND`, even though it works for everyone else
- I have a sneaking suspicion that this has to do with Yarn, but cannot find evidence to this, and using npx fails the same way using yarn does
- fresh installs of the repo and node have not helped, nor has clearing yarn's cache